# turning 'dict' output result into one string in python

Tags: python, string, text, nlp, arabic

I'm using [Farasa](https://farasa.qcri.org/lemmatization/) library and I'm using its lemmatization module that I want to add to my nlp text cleaning code
I've used this code

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://farasa.qcri.org/webapi/lemmatization/'
text = 'ينظم معهد الشارقة للفنون معرضاً فنياً تحت عنوان باقة الفن، وذلك عند الساعة السابعة من مساء اليوم في مقر المعهد في منطقة الفنون في حي الشويهين في الشارقة، وتتلاقى في المعرض إبداعات 62 طالباً من المنتسبين للدراسة في المعهد في كافة التخصصات الفنية .' 
api_key = "####"
payload = {'text': text, 'api_key': api_key}
data = requests.post(url, data=payload)
result = json.loads(data.text)

print(result)
```

and I got this result :

```
{'text': ['نظم', 'معهد', 'شارقة', 'فن', 'معرض', 'فني', 'تحت', 'عنوان', 'باقة', 'فن', '،', 'ذلك', 'عند', 'ساعة', 'سابع', 'من', 'مساء', 'يوم', 'في', 'مقر', 'معهد', 'في', 'منطقة', 'فن', 'في', 'حي', 'شويه', 'في', 'شارقة', '،', 'تلاقى', 'في', 'معرض', 'إبداع', '62', 'طالب', 'من', 'منتسب', 'دراسة', 'في', 'معهد', 'في', 'كافة', 'تخصص', 'فني', '.']}
```

I don't know the output type so I added `print(type(result))`  and I got `<class 'dict'>`
I tried using str() to convert it or .join() but I couldn't get any results

I want to end up with a clean string without those commas and {text} like this

```
نظم معهد شارقة فن معرض فني تحت عنوان باقة فن ، ذلك عند ساعة سابع من مساء يوم في مقر معهد في منطقة فن في حي شويه في شارقة ، تلاقى في معرض إبداع 62 طالب من منتسب دراسة في معهد في كافة تخصص فني
```

and I don't know how.

Comment: "I want to end up with a clean string that has the whole sentence without those commas and {text} and I don't know how." - wait. What? It doesn't sound like you want to do lemmatization at all, then. It sounds like you just want the original sentence, `text`, that you had in the first place.

Comment: Sorry I edited it, I wanted to have it like the original input `text` after the lemmatization .

Answer (score 1):

You could get text list by `result['text']`, then join it.

```
print(' '.join(result['text']))
```